# How can I solved this mod-wsgi installation error on windows 10?

Tags: python, visual-studio, apache, pip, mod-wsgi

I'm working on a small project with Django, for which I wanted to use with the Apache web server, but unfortunately when I was installing the mod-wsgi module, I got a big error that I can't find a solution.

I would ask for your great help to solve it, here I send you the installation error.
Thank you very much in advance.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install mod-wsgi
Collecting mod-wsgi
  Using cached mod_wsgi-4.7.1.tar.gz (498 kB)
Installing collected packages: mod-wsgi
    Running setup.py install for mod-wsgi ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\cristhian\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Cristhian\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xry09hvg\\mod-wsgi\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Cristhian\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xry09hvg\\mod-wsgi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Cristhian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bc24obeb\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\cristhian\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\mod-wsgi'
         cwd: C:\Users\Cristhian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xry09hvg\mod-wsgi\
    Complete output (33 lines):
    c:\users\cristhian\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi
    copying src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\apxs_config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\environ.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management
    copying src\server\management\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    copying src\server\management\commands\runmodwsgi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    copying src\server\management\commands\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\docs
    copying docs\_build\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\docs
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\images
    copying images\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\images
    copying images\snake-whiskey.jpg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\images
    running build_ext
    building 'mod_wsgi.server.mod_wsgi' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src\server
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\AppServ\Apache24/include -Ic:\users\cristhian\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\cristhian\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/server\mod_wsgi.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src/server\mod_wsgi.obj
    mod_wsgi.c
    C:\Users\Cristhian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xry09hvg\mod-wsgi\src\server\wsgi_apache.h(42): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'httpd.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\cristhian\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Cristhian\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xry09hvg\\mod-wsgi\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Cristhian\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xry09hvg\\mod-wsgi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Cristhian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bc24obeb\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\cristhian\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\mod-wsgi' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682741/nmake-error-trying-to-use-python-with-wamp

Comment: https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/278